# Javascript JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json

I try to use JSON.parse(), but  I have error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

working

```
JSON.parse('{"inputType":"select", "rules" :[{"rule": "literal_values", "restriction": "US"}]}')
```

but not working

[image]

why the second version not working?

typeof(validRules) is string

Comment: Works for me...Can you reproduce in a jsFiddle?

Comment: There is no reason this would produce different results. Are you sure you have the exact same string in your test environment?

Comment: sorry, i have updated my question

Comment: please paste output of "typeof (validRules)" if it is string then your code is ok but if its o/p is object then you are doing it wrong.

Comment: typeof (validRules) is string

Comment: then your syntex JSON.parse(validRules) is correct

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot shows the single-quotes as characters within the string's value.

```
console.log(JSON.parse("'{\"inputType\":\"select\"}'"))
//                      ^                          ^
// SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

```
console.log(validRules.charAt(0));     // "'" vs. "{"
console.log(validRules.charCodeAt(0)); // 39  vs. 123
```

While, in your snippet, they're acting as the delimiters for the string literal.

```
console.log(JSON.parse('{"inputType":"select"}'))
// { inputType: 'select' }
```

You'll need to remove the single-quotes from the string value for it to be parsed as JSON.